# safest way to read clob into xml parser

Tags: java, oracle

I'm getting an input stream from a Clob in oracle 11 (using the the oracle 11 jdbc driver), and passing the input stream to an xml parser in Java:

```
java.sql.Clob clob = resultSet.getClob("myClob");
InputStream is = clob.getAsciiStream();
MyDom dom = MyDomParser.parse(is);
```

Wondering if using  a CharacterStream would be safer? e.g instead:

```
Reader r = clob.getCharacterStream();
MyDom dom = MyDomParser.parse(r);
```

My thinking is that getCharacterStream() might be doing some encoding that helps guarantee   nice UTF-8 is returned. Not sure if there is any real difference between the two ways shown here of reading the clob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much difference, getCharacterStream is better for unicode data. Check the link 
http://community.actian.com/wiki/Manipulating_SQL_CLOB_data_with_JDBC

Comment: The link requires you to register to read it.  Unhelpful.  This is **worse** than a link-only answer.