# How to convert a clob type to XML?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to retrieve data from the database which returns CLOB object, and I need to convert it to XML format to read data from it. what is the safest way to do it?

I tried retrieving it using java.sql but it was retrieved as a string, and I want to use it as an object that I can get data from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [safest way to read clob into xml parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536884/safest-way-to-read-clob-into-xml-parser)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Connection connection = <YOUR_CONNECTION_OBJECT>;

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(<YOUR_CLOB_SELECT_REQUEST>);

ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

if (resultSet.next()) {
    Clob clob = resultSet.getClob(<CLOB_COLUMN_NAME>);
}
```